# Apache 500 error, I dont fully understand the error log

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, mod-ssl

I'm trying to connect a backend server(gitorious running in https) to my frontend apache2 server running on ubuntu server. I believe that I have the vhost file and proxy config setup right but it still does not work as I am getting a 500 internal server error.  I checked the error log and found what is below. I think it wants me to load other modules, I have enabled mod_ssl and proxy prior to this.

Does anyone know what modules it is asking me to enable or what might be the problem?

I found this standing out in the apache2 error log

```
[Wed Jan 30 17:53:43 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the 
URL /gitorious. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy
submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Just in case this is what is in my vhost file on the mainserver

```
 SSLProxyEngine On
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyPass /gitorious https://192.168.1.168
 ProxyPassReverse /gitorious https://192.168.1.168
```

Comment: `make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule`: Did you include all of the required modules in the configuration file? There is more then one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the proxy module -

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Then restart apache.